# How to generate access tokens for different users (different domain / instance urls) in JIRA REST API?

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I don't know if I asked the right question. I am creating a web app where users can login, authorize their JIRA account and view a list of projects / issues they have.

First I created a JIRA auth app like this:

[JIRA My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8VOE.png)

and in my code I used the client ID and secret like this:

[Express code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPhXu.png)

After authorizing the user from the web app, I am able to generate an access_token

In order to get issues from JIRA you have to make a request and pass a header Authorization: Bearer [access_token] on this URL

`https://[your-domain].atlassian.net/rest/api/3/search`

Of course, the domain will vary depending on the user who logged in.

What happens is that if I try to authorize another JIRA account, it won't work because I can only generate tokens if I logged in the account that I used to create the Oauth app.